# Amazon t2.mikro for Jenkins testing

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, jenkins

I got 3-4 small projects which I want to test with nightwatch and some up-requests. Is it possible to host jenkins on the small EC2 Instance of Amazon? Since this are only small projects with little income I don´t want to spend too much on the server for jenkins.

Other options? I got a Intel Atom D2700 with 2 GB here, but the fan is annoying as f*.. and jenkins seem to run not very well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [some reference docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/hardware-recommendations/)

> The amount of memory Jenkins needs is largely dependent on many
>   factors, which is why the RAM allotted for it can range from 200 MB
>   for a small installation to 70+ GB for a single and massive Jenkins
>   master. However, you should be able to estimate the RAM required based
>   on your project build needs.
>
> Each build node connection will take 2-3 threads, which equals about 2
>   MB or more of memory. You will also need to factor in CPU overhead for
>   Jenkins if there are a lot of users who will be accessing the Jenkins
>   user interface.
>
> It is generally a bad practice to allocate executors on a master, as
>   builds can quickly overload a master’s CPU/memory/etc and crash the
>   instance, causing unnecessary downtime. Instead, it is advisable to
>   set up agents that the Jenkins master can delegate jobs to, keeping
>   the bulk of the work off of the masteritself.

A t2.micro has 1GB of RAM, which may be sufficient for testing. If you run out of RAM just move up to a larger t2 instance. Yes a t2.micro can be free for a year, but a t2.large with 8GB of RAM is only $0.128/hr. Turn it off when you're not using it and all you pay for is disk storage, which is $0.12/GB/month for general purpose SSD network attached storage (EBS).

Comment: There is also t2.small and t2.medium in between.

Comment: Yes, probably good to point that out, I figured people would work out there were instance sizes between micro and large :)

Comment: Sounds good. My tasks are pretty "small" - i guess then the cpu would be the problem. I will try it out and give my feedback.